# How do I define mappers in Scala for a Cassandra sink in Flink?

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-flink, datastax-java-driver

From the code piece

```
CassandraSink.addSink(result)
        .setHost("127.0.0.1")
        .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true)})
        .build();
```

as illustrated in the [flink docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/cassandra/). How can

```
.setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true)})
```

be translated to scala?

The mapper is coming from `com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper`

Answer (score 0):

The Mapper API you referenced comes from the Cassandra Java driver so it is only available in Java. Cheers!